# What is the kanji for いもうと?

Tags: kanji, etymology

I don’t remember that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seriously... use google. I just wrote "imouto kanji" and got 200000 pages telling me the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that word "妹"?

That's mean younger sister.

Comment: No it doesn't mean "older sister". :)

Comment: dude... 妹 is younger sister. 姉 is older sister.